# How to Print the custom item renderer images in Advanced Datagrids

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

We have developed a web application by using flex-blazeDS-Java. Now we got a requirement that to print the user existed page whenever he clicks on Print button. I am able to print my flex components and advanced datagrid but not able to print the custom item renderer images which are rendered in datagrid. And also how to print the multiple pages when I have large data in advanced datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Use PrintAdvancedDataGrid for printing purposes. Use the same custom itemRenderer so that the same images appear. The PrintAdvancedDataGrid will provide functionality to help pagination.

From Adobe documentation:

// Queue the first page.
printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
// While there are more pages, print them.
while (thePrintView.myDataGrid.validNextPage) {
    //Put the next page of data in the view.
    thePrintView.myDataGrid.nextPage();
    //Queue the additional page.
    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
}

For more info, check out: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=printing_5.html

Comment: I have been using the same printAdavancedDatagrid for printng data grid. But it is missing the column item renderer images in printed sheet.